# Running a script with upstart server in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: bash, ubuntu, upstart

I have a script named **rotate.sh**. After `chmod +x rotate.sh`, I can run it with the command `/home/lin/Desktop/rotate.sh`, and my screen will rotate left.

**rotate.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
xrandr --output VGA1 --rotate left
```

Then I write a upstart job named **testOne**, located in **/etc/init/testOne.conf**.

**testOne.conf:**

```
description "test upstart job"
author "Lin a@i.com"

start on filesystem or runlevel [2345]
start on desktop-session-start
stop on shutdown

pre-start script
    mkdir -p /home/lin/Desktop/test1
end script

respawn
respawn limit 15 5

script
    exec /home/lin/Desktop/rotate.sh 
    cd /home/lin/Desktop/
    mkdir test2
end script
```

But when I run `sudo start testOne`, it doesn't work. Only the **pre-start** works. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps changing this line

```
exec /home/lin/Desktop/rotate.sh
```

to

```
exec /home/lin/Desktop/rotate.sh start
```

would help. As an alternative, you can also use exec stanzas instead of simple cases, in which case, it would be something like this

```
exec bash -c '/home/lin/Desktop/rotate.sh start'
```

Check out some reference here on [upstart](https://launchpad.net/upstart) and how to work with it: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#id300